# React testing with Jest : Destructuring assignment not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, destructuring

I am trying to test a react component using Jest and Enzyme. My `componentDidMount` method/function

```
Real.jsx

// some code

class MyComponent extends React.Component {


    componentDidMount() {
      setTimeout (() => {
        const { formVals : { eName, eSal }, changeVal } = this.props
        console.log("changeVal function" + changeVal)
        changeVal(someparam , someparam2)
      }, 1000)
    }

// some more functions 

}

export default MyComponent
```

and my test code goes like

```
import MyComponent from '../../components/Real' //Real.jsx

    jest.useFakeTimers();
    test('test componentDidMount', () => {
      var props = {
        formVals: {
          eName: 123,
          eSal: 10000
        },
        changeVal: (x, y) => console.log(x)
      }
    
      var component = shallow <MyComponent {...props}/>
      jest.runAllTimers(); // getting coverage for setTimeOut
      component.update();  // getting coverage for setTimeOut
    })
```

But I get the value of changeVal as undefined which means destructuring assignment is not working.

Kindly help on what might be an issue in this case.

Comment: Voting to close. Looks to be caused by a typo (missing colon) in `const { formVals { eName, eSal }, changeVal } = this.props;` versus `const { formVals: { eName, eSal }, changeVal } = this.props;` for renaming `formVals` and destructuring into `eName` and `eSal`.

Comment: I already had a colon :  there . but the destructuring doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Is the component under test `MyComponent` the same component the `componentDidMount` lifecycle function is a part of? Can you update your question to include the *entire* component code including how it's exported, and also how it's imported for testing?

Comment: Yes ,its  the same component .

Comment: added the complete code of the component and test case

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
const { 
  formVals: { eName, eSal },
  changeVal
} = this.props;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
     const { formVals : { eName, eSal }, changeVal } = this.props
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `const { formVals { eName, eSal }, changeVal } = this.props`

to

```
const { formVals, changeVal } = this.props;
const { eName, eSal } = formVals;
```

or

```
const { formVals: { eName, eSal }, changeVal } = this.props
```

Update: Trying the repro the issue with snippet.
Only change is I had to remove the `;` at end of console.log to avoid error.

```js
var props = {
  formVals: {
    eName: 123,
    eSal: 10000,
  },
  changeVal: (x, y) => console.log(x)
};

const {
  formVals: { eName, eSal },
  changeVal,
} = props;

changeVal("print this", "hello");
```

Comment: it was already this : const { formVals: { eName, eSal }, changeVal } = this.props. and yet the assignment is not working and changeVal is undefined.

Comment: @RajeevAkotkar, Oh ok, That's interesting. I tried to see the issue you are facing with snippet. Can you remove the `;` at end of console.log inside the object and try.

Comment: Sorry ,that was yet another typo. I don't have ; at the end of function . Does jest.FakeTimers(),jest.runAllTimers() and component.update () have a role to play in this.Are the props getting washed off due to that

Comment: while I print this.props , I get to see all the properties apart from  changeVal.